# how to run hexo in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, express, subdirectory, hexo

As title,
I want to run hexo in http://here/blog, so I tried edit `_config` like this:

```
url: http://here/blog
root: /blog/
```

but after `hexo generate`, the link in the `index.html` look like this

```
<script src="/js/pace.js"></script>
```

but not

```
<script src="/blog/js/pace.js"></script>
```

this is my directory looks like

```
main
├app.js  <-main js
├blog    <-the folder which hexo generate gives me
├ ...something other
```

thanks you help!

Answer (score 0):

What you done seems correct as stated in the [hexo documents](https://hexo.io/docs/configuration.html#URL). Also, this was broken in Hexo before 3.2 like stated in [this issue](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/1775).

Are you using latest hexo? If not, could you please inform you version?